# Access Denied to local document, offering to request permission on SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-office, sharepoint

A colleague of mine has encountered this error while trying to access a document on a file share.
[image: Access Denied | You do not have access to view this file. Would you like to request for permission on Sharepoint?]

> **Access Denied**
>
> You do not have access to view this file. Would you like to request for permission on Sharepoint?

This apparently happens with a document in a <s>local/</s>network folder, not on SharePoint/Onedrive.

I can't find any other reference to the message online.

Does anyone know what this error means?

EDIT: it's slightly inconsistent, but only seems to happen on some files.  For us it's happening in a PowerPoint file.  I can access the file if I make a copy within the same folder on the share.

I personally have only reproduced this on a network share, and am currently wondering if it's something to do with Offline Files?

Comment: What happens when the request access?  [It was either a file shared through Teams or OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/files/do-not-have-access-to-this-file-teams)

Comment: When I request access I get a security warning ("Some files can contain viruses or otherwise..."), if I click OK I seem to get a "blank" Powerpoint window, from which I can click File to open a document or create a new one.

Comment: This is likely a credential issue. I have seen this before.  Ask the Sharepoint provider

Answer (score 1):

I had a user with the exact same issue.  The HP security software (wolf) was causing the issue. It caused issues with MSAccess as well. once removed everything functioned properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue, and found a workaround/fix:

Machine: Windows 10 21H2
Office:  365 Apps for enterprise
Powerpoint: Version 2302 (Build 16130.20218 c2r)
Dell: HP wolf software is not involved.

In our case, the symptoms were as follows:

1. Error "You do not have access to view this file. Would you like to request permission on Sharepoint?" occurs when opening Powerpoint files through folder redirection.
2. Affected folder was on desktop.
3. Folder preview was enabled.

The strange fix I found was:

1. Disable the preview pane in File Explorer (View > click Preview Pane to turn it off.)

As soon as I turned of the preview pane, the issue stopped happening.  I tested multiple times turning the preview pane on and off, and it consistently stopped the issue from occurring.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Preview Pane was a surprise for me as well, that fixed it. I later ran a Quick Repair of Office and I can now enable the Preview Pane. Files open without an error message.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1189357)

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this for the first time today. Coincidentally I've begun building Sharepoint document libraries to replace mapped drives. So this message popping up really had my user upset at Sharepoint. Kinda funny.

I use Cisco Umbrella for DNS security, which causes an occasional problem on my network whereby a W10 computer will think it is not connected to the Internet (have not seen this behavior in W11). Everything works as expected, but the Microsoft Office apps and the network connection icon in the systray will say there is no connection. Powerpoint will display this message while this is the case. (Outlook will say it needs a password, Word is just erratic).

A quick ipconfig /release and /renew fixed it in the immediate term.

Comment: Hello, 90% of answer is a description of a problem, not a solution. It should usuall be the other way round (or with no problem describing at all).